# Website not completely scrollable when using skrollr on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, skrollr

I have a hard time getting skrollr to work on mobile browsers:
On my desktop computer everything works fine but when using Safari for iOS my page is not completely scrollable. You can scroll e.g. until to the second paragraph but no further.

I've tested this for Safari on iOS but not with any other mobile browsers.

Paradoxically it works well on the jsfiddle preview I've created:
http://jsfiddle.net/gatL4ttn/3/
http://jsfiddle.net/gatL4ttn/3/embedded/result/

It does not work with my self hosted version:
http://www.finiam.de/test

```
     <div
        class="parallax-image-wrapper parallax-image-wrapper-100"
        data-anchor-target=".gap"
        data-bottom-top="transform:translate3d(0px, 200%, 0px)"
        data-top-bottom="transform:translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px)">

        <div
            class="parallax-image parallax-image-100"
            style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/g/2000/1000)"
            data-anchor-target=".gap"
            data-bottom-top="transform: translate3d(0px, -80%, 0px);"
            data-top-bottom="transform: translate3d(0px, 80%, 0px);">
      </div>
        <!--the +/-80% translation can be adjusted to control the speed difference of the image-->
    </div>


    <div id="skrollr-body">
        <div class="gap gap-100" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/g/2000/1000);">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="abc" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" title="Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.">A Hyperlink</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="content" id="main">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
              <p>
                Donec dui ante, posuere sit amet rutrum vel, suscipit lacinia nisl. Praesent euismod erat sed tempor iaculis. Integer luctus est vel nulla dapibus porttitor sit amet eget ante. Nullam eleifend leo lacinia rutrum gravida. Nunc convallis, lacus sed malesuada gravida, justo urna aliquam mi, sit amet sollicitudin lacus urna non mauris. Vivamus a ante a lectus vestibulum aliquam et quis sapien. Vivamus nec augue interdum, mollis risus eu, tempor libero. Curabitur at tempus dui. Mauris cursus massa at sodales semper. Aenean varius dui consectetur enim sagittis consectetur.
              </p>
              <p>
                 Bla Bla Bla Bla
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is driving me mad and help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nico,

It appears as though skrollr-body is getting confused with the div called gap. Try this:

Remove the .row div from the .gap div, and delete the .gap div entirely.

take and add 200px (or however many works with your design) of padding to the bottom of .row:

```
.row{ padding-bottom: 200px; }
```

With .gap removed, and the padding on the row element, this should synthesize what you need.

I suspect that .gap is the issue because when I inspected the element in Chrome, it highlighted skrollr-body around only the .gap div.